# Right half plane zero calculation

Tags: boost, switching-regulator

I'd like to use the [Micrel MIC2606](http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/mic2605.pdf) boost converter for a 36 volt circuit I'm working on. The datasheet gives a formula for calculating the RHP zero based on output voltage, current, and inductor value.

I'm also using the TI app report discussing feedback loop analysis for boost converters [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva633/slva633.pdf):

1. What is the **D** in the formula?
2. Does it have to do with the size of the loop between Vin and the SW node?
3. Out of habit, I was planning on keeping that loop as small as possible and away from sensitive circuits but are there any other general guidelines I should use when developing this circuit?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the D in the formula?

Duty cycle of the PWM.

> Does it have to do with the size of the loop between Vin and the SW
>   node?

Not directly - the loop as you call it is the inductor and there are trade-offs to be made between duty cycle and inductor value for a particular set of power and load scenarios.

> Out of habit, I was planning on keeping that loop as small as possible
>   and away from sensitive circuits but are there any other general
>   guidelines I should use when developing this circuit?

The data sheet should give useful PCB design rules and guidelines but in addition I would say wire incoming power ground directly to the PGND on the chip and have output capacitor and input capacitor directly connected to this point. Tee-off from this point to provide a clean ground for the lower resistor in the feedback chain, the Vcc cap and the SS cap.

Answer (score 1):

1. D is the Duty Cycle

[image]

If you read the datasheet in its entirety, it will probably answer questions 2 and 3.